# How to handle multiple subscribtions to private subjects exposed by asObservable()

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm following a common pattern where an Angular service has a private `Subject` that exposes a public `Observable` like this:

```
private somethingSubject = new Subject<number>();
something$ = this.somethingSubject.asObservable();
```

In my specific case it makes sense to keep the subject private but how do I make this available for multiple subscribers?

In other words, subjects are multi cast while observers are single cast. Can I get a multi cast observable while preventing outside components from calling .next on the subject?

Comment: You'll have just one instance of `something$`. Or maybe I don't understand your question.

Comment: But aren't observables single cast while subjects are multicast. Is it possible to have it multicast but prevent other components from being able to change the subject?

Answer (score 1):

This may not answer your question but I think a `shareReplay(1)` might help you to make the observable multicast.

Something like this:

```
import { shareReplay } from 'rxjs/operators';
....
private somethingSubject = new Subject<number>();
something$ = this.somethingSubject.asObservable().pipe(shareReplay(1));
```

Hopefully you're `something$` stream is more complicated than that because the reason for `shareReplay` (or the reason I see the need for `shareReplay`) is so it doesn't do same logic over and over again for multiple subscribers thereby gaining a bit of speed.

Whenever you consume `something$`, it will have a replayed observable (making the observable hot) so it may have unintended consequences. Make sure you always unsubscribe on destruction to get rid of this unintended consequences.

You can unsubscribe using `takeUntil` operator.

```
this.somethingElse$ = this.something$.pipe(
  takeUntil(this.destructionSubject),
);
```

Read more about `shareReplay` [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/multicasting/sharereplay)